# cannot connect to oracle db from apache nifi

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-nifi

Not able to connect to Oracle db from NIFI which I installed on AWS EC2. But I am able to ping to the db server from the same EC2 instance

```
QueryDatabaseTable[id=####] Unable to execute SQL select query SELECT * FROM CC_REPORTS.CC_CALLS due to java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:Oracle:thin:@'###.###.###.25:1521/CIDB': org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:Oracle:thin:@###.###.###.25:1521/CIDB'
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`? (And `jdbc:oracle:...`, not sure if case matters there though...)

Comment: @Samy, you have to put ojdbc*.jar into nifi lib folder or specify the location of this jar in connection properties

Comment: Finally found the reason.. the SID was incorrect. changed it to CI ifrom CIDB and its working now.